# How put colored image in pdf file, using laravel php and dompdf?

Tags: laravel, image, pdf, dompdf

My image is coming black and white and the original image is a .png white and blue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WFVN.png)

Comment: Could you please include an example of the code you are currently using?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this turned out to be because ImageMagick wasn't installed on our server. DomPDF should probably check for its existence before attempting to generate PDFs containing PNG files?

Just for the record, here are the steps I was required to take to install ImageMagick on IIS:

- Uninstall existing imagick installations and DLL extensions from PHP
- Install imagick `ImageMagick-6.6.2-10-Q16-windows-dll` from [here](http://image_magick.veidrodis.com/image_magick/binaries/).
- Add latest version of thread safe (ts) or non-thread safe (nts) dll, for example `php_imagick_nts.dll`, to PHP extension dir from [this link](http://valokuva.org/builds/).
- Add `extension=php_imagick_nts.dll` to php.ini
- Run following cmd command to add IIS permissions to temporary directory: `cacls c:\windows\temp /E /C /G iusr_SERVERNAME:R`

It's worth noting that the last statement may be considered insecure on working installations. You can change the imagick temporary directory in the configuration settings, but personally I couldn't get it working.